# Cannot use scatterplot in Octave

Tags: matrix, vector, dataset, octave, scatter-plot

I was learning how to do machine learning on mldata.org and I was watching a video on Youtube on how to use the data (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zY0UhXPy8fM) (2:50). Using the same data, I tried to follow exactly what he did and create a scatterplot of the dataset. However when he used the scatterplot command, it worked perfectly on his side, but I cannot do it on myside.

Can anyone explain what's wrong and what I should do?

```
octave:2> load banana_data.octave
octave:3> pkg load communications
octave:4> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        data        2x5300                   84800  double
        label       1x5300                   42400  double

Total is 15900 elements using 127200 bytes
octave:5> scatterplot(data, label)
error: scatterplot: real X must be a vector or a 2-column matrix
error: called from:
error:   /home/anthony/octave/communications-1.2.0/scatterplot.m at line 69, column 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. Your `data` is a `2-row matrix`, and not a `2-column matrix` as it should be. Just transpose it with `.'`.

```
scatterplot(data.')
```

I dropped the `label` argument since it is not compatible with the `communications` toolbox, either in [matlab](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/comm/scatterplot.html) or in octave.

**Update**:

According to `news('communications')`,

> The plotting functions `eyediagram' and`scatterplot' have improved Matlab compatibility

This may be why the behaviour is different. Be ready to find other glitches, as the octave 3.2.4 used in this course is about 5 years old.

In order to use the `label`, you should rather use the standard octave `scatter` function.
Colors could be changed by choosing another `colormap`.

```
colormap(cool(256))
scatter(data(1,:), data(2,:), 6, label, "filled")
```

[image: with scatter]

Comment: Thanks, that seems to get the data to be plotted correctly, but when I try to plot both the data and the label (scatterplot(data.', label)
), I get this error message: "scatterplot: N must be a positive integer"

How do I fix that?

Comment: It works, thanks!

Though I am curious, do you mind explaining the syntax of "scatter(data(1,:), data(2,:), 6, label, "filled")"  (I am a bit new to octave)

Comment: @user3377126 Just type `help scatter`, it will explain the syntax.